# :hover on an element to change another?

Tags: html, css, hover, html-lists

I have this bar chart and I would like to change the "test div" to a different background-color and the content itself when I'm hovering a specific bar.

I have a bit trouble trying to make an element:hover change another element.

I know there are many similar questions about this topic, but none of them seems to do the trick for me.

### HTML:

```
<div class="the-container">
    <ul>
        <li><a class="html" href="#"></a></li>
        <li><a class="css" href="#"></a></li>
        <li><a class="photoshop" href="#"></a></li>
        <li><a class="illustrator" href="#"></a></li>
        <li><a class="javascript" href="#"></a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="test"><p>Hello</p></div>
</div>
```

### CSS:

```
.the-container { width:300px; height:250px; background-color:#EEE; }

.the-container ul { margin:0; padding:0; list-style:none; }

.the-container li { width:40px; height:250px; margin:0 10px; position:relative; float:left;}

.the-container li a { position:absolute; bottom:0; width:100%; height:0; background-color:#ccc; border-top-left-radius: 5px; border-top-right-radius: 5px;}

.the-container li a.html:hover { background-color:#111; }
.the-container li a.css:hover { background-color:#ef3ef3; }
.the-container li a.photoshop:hover { background-color:#be3be3; }
.the-container li a.illustrator:hover { background-color:#cd3cd3; }
.the-container li a.javascript:hover { background-color:#888; }

div.test{width:300px; height: 30px; background-color:#BBB; position: relative; clear:both; line-height:2; margin-top:-16px;}

div.test p {text-align: center;}

a.html:hover ~ div.test{background-color:yellow;}
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hgLkT/)**

Any ideas?
Much appreciated!

Comment: Are you looking for a CSS only solution?

Comment: The sibling selector (~) only selects direct siblings. Your `<div>` is not a sibling of the `<a>` tag. I don't think there's any way to do what you want with pure CSS

Comment: Yep this looks like a javascript task

Comment: @StephenThomas is right, it can't be done with CSS.

Comment: As @StephenThomas said you can't with just CSS because you need a stepback for the parent `ul`

Comment: @j08691 Yeah, if it's possible to do it with CSS only I would prefer that. But it seems to be a job for JavaScript. Thank you.

Comment: @user3092784 Because you're targeting an element that would require traversing back up the DOM tree in order to select with CSS (i.e. from the `a`s to `div.test`), it is impossible with CSS only, as CSS selectors only allow for child/ancestor/sibling traversal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you are only able to select siblings and children with CSS.  To be able to target `.test` you would need to apply `:hover` on either the `ul` or container `div`.

A detailed explanation of child and sibling selectors in CSS can be found [here](http://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/).

### Update

Whilst I'm not a fan of the semantics, here is an POC example of how it could work using CSS and changing the structure of the markup.

```
<div class="the-container">
<ul>
    <li class="item-html"><a class="html" href="#"></a></li>
    <li><a class="css" href="#"></a></li>
    <li><a class="photoshop" href="#"></a></li>
    <li><a class="illustrator" href="#"></a></li>
    <li><a class="javascript" href="#"></a></li>
    <li><div class="test"><p>Hello</p></div></li>
</ul>
</div>

.item-html:hover ~ li div.test { background: yellow; }
```

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hgLkT/6/)

Comment: You may want to clarify because he isn't trying to select any parent

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I see.. Anyway of making this happend with CSS only and another markup?

Answer (score 0):

You can't with pure `CSS`, since you're already using jQuery, why not do something like:

```
$(".the-container a").hover(
    function() {
       $('.test').css("background","orange");
       $('.test').html("<p>text changed</p>");
    }, function() {
       $('.test').css("background","#bbb");
       $('.test').html("<p>Hello</p>");
    }
);
```

You could replace `.css` with `addClass` and `removeClass` as well.

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/hgLkT/2/)

Comment: I would opt very strongly for replacing it with `addClass` and `removeClass`, so that JavaScript isn't concerned with CSS styles, only markup classes.

Comment: Just a note, please don't use this solution as it is now, or every single Anchor in your site will cause the event to trigger...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a jQUery solution?

```
$( '.the-container ul li a' ).mouseover(function() {
   $('.test').css("background-color", $(this).css('background-color'));
});

$( '.the-container ul li a' ).mouseout(function() {
   $('.test').css("background-color", "#BBB");
});
```

Alternatively, use `.addClass("colored_test")` and `.removeClass("colored_test")` instead of `.css(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to change your colors and text:

**JavaScript**

```
$('.illustrator').mouseover(function(){
    $('.test').css({backgroundColor:'#cd3cd3'});
    $('.test p').html('Illustrator');
});
$('.illustrator').mouseout(function(){
    $('.test').css({backgroundColor:'#BBB'});
    $('.test p').html('');
});
```

**[Complete Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/35KFD/9/)**

Comment: There's no need for that much code duplication, this could be re-factored, by doing something like this in the `hover` function: `$('.test').css("background",$(this).css("background-color"));`

Comment: @NickR Thanks, that is a whole lot better.  I'll update the link in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery's [hover()](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_hover.asp) and [css()](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_css.asp) functions.

```
    $('li a').hover(function(){
        $('.test').css('background-color', $(this).css('background-color'));
    });
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Sionnach733/hgLkT/4/)

Answer (score 0):

You could combine your CSS sibling selector with a bit of jquery and be good to go

Use css to control the colors as you attempted (*whitespace is just for visual aid*)

```
.html        ~ .test{background-color:#111;}
.css         ~ .test{background-color:#ef3ef3;}
.photoshop   ~ .test{background-color:#be3be3;}
.illustrator ~ .test{background-color:#cd3cd3;}
.javascript  ~ .test{background-color:#888;}
```

but use jquery to apply the class to the `ul` as well on `mouseenter`/`mouseout`

```
var ul = $('.the-container ul');
ul.on('mouseenter mouseleave', 'a', function(){
    ul.toggleClass( this.className );
});
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/hgLkT/5/

Answer (score 0):

For CSS only* solution you'll need to update structure a little bit.

IE:

```
<div class="the-container">
    <ul>
        <li class="html"><a href="#"></a></li>
        <li class="css"><a href="#"></a></li>
        <li class="photoshop"><a href="#"></a></li>
        <li class="illustrator"><a href="#"></a></li>
        <li class="javascript"><a href="#"></a></li>
        <li class="test"><p>Hello</p></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Here's an updated example: http://jsfiddle.net/hgLkT/8/

**It's not a real CSS only solution, because you are already using JS to animate the height of the bars.*